# Error "File not found" saving ActiveWorkbook

Tags: excel, vba

I'm getting an error for the line after the comment in the code below.

```
Sub SyncToDatabase()

    Dim WS1 As Worksheet
    Set WS1 = Sheets("Observation Form")
    DbFile = WS1.Range("O3").Value
    LastLocalChange = WS1.Range("O5").Value
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(DbFile)
    If objFile.DateLastModified < LastLocalChange Then
        Kill (DbFile)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Output(Hidden)").Copy

        ' i get the error on the next line
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs DbFile, FileFormat:=51

        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If

End Sub
```

Error message is

> "File not found"

The file path is "C:\Users\paul.d_wsd\Google Drive\Winchester\Science Department\Lessons Learned\Lessons Learned Excel Converted (Database).xlsm"

Comment: It may help to state the error and error details.

Comment: And the value of `DbFile`

Comment: **1.** What is the error message? **2.** What is the value of `DbFile`?

Comment: Apologies, I'm new to VBA.
Error message is..."File not found"
However, the file path is correctly added.
C:\Users\paul.d_wsd\Google Drive\Winchester\Science Department\Lessons Learned\Lessons Learned Excel Converted (Database).xlsm

Comment: You cannot get that error("File not found") on the `.SaveAs` line. Are you sure you are not getting that error in `Kill (DbFile)`? Try this for me. Put `On Error Resume Next` before `Kill (DbFile)` and `On Error GoTo 0` After `Kill (DbFile)`. Do you still get the error?

Comment: @SiddharthRout
After doing that, I got the same error at:
"Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(DbFile)"

Comment: Perfect now try this. Paste `MsgBox Dir(dbfile)` after the line `DbFile = WS1.Range("O3").Value`.  What do you get?

Comment: I get an empty message box with a heading of, "Microsoft Excel".

Comment: I suspected it. I posted an answer. you may want to refresh the page to see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment, you cannot get the error "File not found" on the `.SaveAs` line. Before you use a File in `Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(DbFile)` and `Kill (DbFile)`, you need to check if the file exists. Else you will get a `File Not Found` error. Here is an example.

```
'~~> Check if DbFile is not empty
If Len(Trim(DbFile)) = 0 Then Exit Sub

'~~> Check if file exists
If Dir(DbFile) <> "" Then
    LastLocalChange = WS1.Range("O5").Value
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set objFile = objFSO.GetFile(DbFile)
    If objFile.DateLastModified < LastLocalChange Then
        Kill (DbFile)
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data Output(Hidden)").Copy
        ' i get the error on the next line (you cannot make code bold)
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs DbFile, FileFormat:=51
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
End If
```